# No concept of "size" in Guava's RangeSet / Range?

Tags: java, range, guava, intervals

I'm eager to use *Guava's RangeSets* in my program. Despite the features of adding and merging of ranges, i'm also interested in the *"size" of my ranges*.

Some remarks:

- no ranges i'm interested in are infinite!
- all ranges i'm using are of the bound-type "closedOpen"
- the underlying use-case is a discrete time-space (size = summed up time-ticks)

This seems to be something which is not built-in (or i didn't see it) and i'm wondering if there is a clear reason against this conceptionally (which means i should not implement some getSize() function myself) or not.

Let's have a look at my use-case:

```
RangeSet<Integer> usageTicks = TreeRangeSet.create();
usageTicks.add(Range.closedOpen(3, 7));
usageTicks.add(Range.closedOpen(12,18));
usageTicks.add(Range.closedOpen(18, 23));

int size = usageTicks.hypotheticalGetSizeFunction(); // size = 15
```

Is there any reason against the following:

```
Set<Range<Integer>> setOfRanges = usageTicks.asRanges();
int sum = 0;
for(Range<Integer> range : setOfRanges)
    sum += (range.upperEndpoint() - range.lowerEndpoint());
```

Comment: If your ranges overlap, you are counting some time steps more than once. Do you want this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? If i add the range Range.closedOpen(14,17) to usageTicks, which overlaps with the rangeSet at this time, the new state of the rangeSet will not change at all ([[3?7), [12?23)]). If a add Range.closedOpen(6,9), the rangeSet will change ([[3?9), [12?23)]), but when iterating and summing nothing will be summed up more than once?

Comment: Ok, my bad, I guess I wasn't understanding what ``RangeSet`` does. I imagined the ``asRanges()`` method would return the same ranges you added initially, in which case, if they had overlapped, we would be summing more than we wanted. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guava's `Range` only require one thing of its enclosed types: that they implement `Comparable`.

But not all which implement `Comparable` have a notion of distance. How would you measure the distance between two `String`s, for instance?

This is why Guava also has [`DiscreteDomain`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html) and [`ContiguousSet`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ContiguousSet.html); with the former you have methods such as `next()`, `prev()` and `distance()`, which is what you are interested in here. Guava's site has an [article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained#Discrete_Domains) on it.

Comment: I feel embarassed. While knowing about DiscreteDomain (or at least read about that on your mentioned article), i never got to these docs listing all the functions. Beautiful! And also thanks for the reasoning about the Comparable-assumption and the not always existing distance-metric (or at least one has to choose like Levenshtein-distance for Strings)!

Comment: No reason to be embarrassed ;) Even though these exist, using them is another matter after all!